# Why is my Activity runs from the top again when resumed instead of doing nothing?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-manifest, activity-lifecycle

I have an activity which displays a table from the database. When I press power button to turn off the screen, then pressing power button again to resume the activity, the table ***loads again*** and does what it did on create. **Why is my activity running again when I resume it?**

I even put **onResume()** and left it blank/default.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}
```

Comment: Can you show your `onPause`?

Comment: what about your `onStart`?

Comment: Thats simple. Because `onCreate()` is invoked again, when you turn on the screen. To check whats going on, you should proabably include a `Log.d("<class name>", "inside <function name>")` in all of those methods and see the logs

Comment: I'm sure it's not calling oncreate again. After you resume Activity It shows fragment's without calling oncreate as it was before locking phone.

Comment: @Michal_196 same as onResume()

Comment: @A.A i did not put onStart() since I don't think it's necessary. do i need to?

Comment: Since you assume that `onCreate` is called again maybe the cause is that your activity was destroyed and forced to recreate (and you didn't saved its state correctly). For an activity to be destroyed, there are 2 main reasons: either the system has run out of memory or you have `Don't keep activities` activated from `Developer options`. Please check the last one to see if it is enabled.

Comment: @Iulian Popescu In my opinion everything is working as supposed to be, but he just doesn't understand fragment lifecycle

Comment: @VygintasB I agree that the underlaying problem is based on the incorrect handling of lifecycle, but there is something in user's code that makes that table to reload again, which is triggered by something (which we don't know exactly at the moment).

Comment: @IulianPopescu I'm sure I have the necessary knowledge about the life cycle... Anyway, I put a Log in my main activity inside onCreate() that displays a text. At first run, it displayed the text, then I pressed the power button on and off and it didn't run the text again meaning it did not recreate the Activity. That's what I want. However, in the Activity where I am having issues, it keeps on recreating the onCreate() thus keeps printing the log.

Comment: You said: "in the Activity where I am having issues, it keeps on recreating the onCreate() thus keeps printing the log". How does this exactly happens?

Comment: everytime I press power button on/off. I can see in the Android monitor it prints the log again and again but in my other activities it only prints once which is what I expected.

Comment: Ok, can you please post the full code of the activity that causes problems?

Comment: im starting to think maybe because off memory problems. this activity is quite heavy because it loops every textview in the table row according to the number of rows in the  database so maybe that's why the system destroys it when onPause

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154115/discussion-between-iulian-popescu-and-elbert-john-felipe).

Comment: guys I also found out that putting android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" in the activity manifest runs the onCreate method twice. it's so annoying. then I found a link that says to put android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize‌​" in my activities manifest after android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape", and it worked. lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accordingly, it will call methods according to as  follows, that will never call for onCreate() so that your data is reloaded,

> On launching Activity it will call --> onCreate(), onStart(), onResume(),
>
> onPower Key Off --> onPause(), onStop()
>
> onPower Key On --> onRestart(), onStart(), onResume()

To prevent reloading your data there are many cases [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948315/activity-lifecycle-x-power-button-x-lock-screen) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302181/how-to-prevent-calls-to-ondestroy-followed-by-oncreate-when-power-button-is)

**May be due to :**

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

Comment: hmm... interesting

Comment: i'm wondering what android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" has to do with the issue, seems odd?

Comment: you are right but this may be the case as it is accepted and voted answer by user and is your issue solved ?@ElbertJohnFelipe

Comment: oh. I also found out that putting android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" in the activity manifest runs the onCreate method twice. it's so annoying.

Comment: that android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize‌​" really does solved the problem/ thanks!